# how to send navigations params to mapStatetoProps method

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I want to put navigation params to mapStatetoProps method

I try to avoid redux for my navigation to keep it simple, but if the only way is to use redux then I'll use it.

here is my code

```
class GameScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
    title: navigation.state.params.id,
  });

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor: '#005662'}}>
        <Text>ID</Text>
        <Text>{this.props.game.id}</Text>
        <Text>TITLE</Text>
        <Text>{this.props.game.title}</Text>
        </View>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state, props) {
  return {
    game: state.games.find(item => item.id === /* how to put value from navigation.state.params.id to here */)
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(GameScreen);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use your ownprops `props.navigation.state.params.id` no need to implement redux

```
function mapStateToProps(state, props) {
  return {
    game: state.games.find(item => item.id === props.navigation.state.params.id)
  }
}
```

shoutout to [nico1510](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/2104#issuecomment-314105199) for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can [integrate](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/blob/master/docs/guides/Redux-Integration.md) `React Navigation` with `Redux` and have the current navigation state in your store.

Then you can easily access that data in your state inside of `mapStateToProps`.

```
function mapStateToProps(state, props) {
  return {
    game: state.games.find(item => item.id === state.nav...
  }
}
```

Comment: I've integrate redux but still can't get the params , can u elaborate more besides `state.nav...`?

Comment: You can check out this link which explains what you would find in your nav state that is populated by `getStateForAction`. What you see in the example for `getStateForAction` is the same structure you have in your nav state.
 https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/blob/93976d358e27580e568ef016f820dc0253423aa7/docs/api/routers/RoutersAPI.md